# Two Concepts of Monotonicity

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a closed convex subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F: K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. We say that

- $F$ is strongly monotone on $K$ if there exists $\gamma>0$ such that

$$
\langle F(y)-F(x), y-x\rangle\geq \gamma\|y-x\|^2, \quad \forall x,y\in K.
$$

- $F$ is strongly pseudomonotone on $K$ if there exists $\gamma>0$ such that
  $$
  \langle F(x), y-x\rangle\geq 0 \Longrightarrow \langle F(y), y-x\rangle\geq \gamma\|y-x\|^2
  $$
  for all $x,y\in K$.

It is easily to verify that strongly monotone implies strongly pseudomonotone.
The converse is not true in general. For example, in one-dimensional case 
$$
F(x)=(2-x), \quad K=[0,1],
$$ 
the mapping $F$ is strongly pseudomonotone but not strongly monotone on $K$.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Can we find a mapping $F: K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n (n\geq 2)$ such that $\text{int}K\ne \emptyset$ ($K$ has a nonempty interior) and $F$ is strongly pseudomonotone but not strongly monotone on $K$. It is interesting to find $\textbf{an affine mapping}$ as in the above example.

I am grateful to all your comments and helping.

Comment: Why isn't the given answer accepted?

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example here:
Modified projection method for strongly pseudomonotone variational inequalities
PD Khanh, PT Vuong, Journal of Global Optimization 58 (2), 341-350